# i am getting error with following query

Tags: postgresql

The following query (wich uses the `crosstab` function to `PIVOT` a table) produces an error:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
 crosstab (
  'SELECT DATE_PART("year", current_date) - DATE_PART("year", i.dob) :: int age_group, 
       month :: text , count (distinct i.id):: int AS total_member 
   FROM insureds i inner join group_plans_insureds gpi on  i.id = gpi.insured_id 
   WHERE group_plan_id = 62 
       and year::text = to_char(date_trunc(''year'', current_date - ''1 month''::interval),''yyyy'')
       and DATE_PART("year", current_date) - DATE_PART("year", i.dob)) between 0 and 21'
  ) 
AS (
  code text,
  "Jan" int,
  "Feb" int,
  "Mar" int,
  "Apr" int,
  "May" int,
  "Jun" int,
  "Jul" int,
  "Aug" int,
  "Sep" int,
  "Oct" int,
  "Nov" int,
  "Dec" int
);
```

produces the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 6: ...T("year", current_date) - DATE_PART("year", i.dob)) between ...

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 6: ...T("year", current_date) - DATE_PART("year", i.dob)) between ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a few things in your query... First and foremost, when you work with a `crosstab`, it is always useful to first check the stringified query you're going to pass to it.

I assume, in your case, it should be this one:

```
   SELECT 
       DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', i.dob) :: int age_group, 
       month :: text , 
       count (distinct i.id) :: int AS total_member 
   FROM 
       insureds i 
       inner join group_plans_insureds gpi on  i.id = gpi.insured_id 
   WHERE 
       group_plan_id = 62 
       and year::text = to_char(date_trunc('year', current_date - '1 month'::interval),'yyyy')
       and DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', i.dob) between 0 and 21
   GROUP BY
       1, 2
```

As a second step, you quote it with a $$ --- $$ delimiters (so, you don't need to worry about converting ' to ''), and pass it to `crosstab`

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
 crosstab (
  $$
   SELECT 
       DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', i.dob) :: int age_group, 
       month :: text , 
       count (distinct i.id) :: int AS total_member 
   FROM 
       insureds i 
       inner join group_plans_insureds gpi on  i.id = gpi.insured_id 
   WHERE 
       group_plan_id = 62 
       and year::text = to_char(date_trunc('year', current_date - '1 month'::interval),'yyyy')
       and DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', i.dob) between 0 and 21
   GROUP BY
       1, 2
   $$
  ) 
AS (
  code text,
  "Jan" int,
  "Feb" int,
  "Mar" int,
  "Apr" int,
  "May" int,
  "Jun" int,
  "Jul" int,
  "Aug" int,
  "Sep" int,
  "Oct" int,
  "Nov" int,
  "Dec" int
);
```

... and this should work.

---

NOTE: If you want a realistic answer, provide the definitions for the tables involved (`insureds` and `group_plans_insureds`), and some sample data.

Comment: thank you but still getting this error    ERROR:  column "month" does not exist
LINE 4:        month :: text , 
               ^

Comment: EIther the `insureds` or `group_plans_insureds` should have this column. How does your original query work?